# Why can't the Rust compiler infer that one argument outlives another?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code:

```rust
struct Solver<'a> {
    guesses: Vec<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> Solver<'a> {
    fn register_guess(&mut self, guess: &'a str) {
        self.guesses.push(guess);
    }
}

fn foo(mut solver: Solver, guess: &str) {
    solver.register_guess(guess)
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
   |
11 | fn foo(mut solver: Solver, guess: &str) {
   |        ----------                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |        |
   |        has type `Solver<'2>`
12 |     solver.register_guess(guess)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

The error message says that the argument `guess` must outlive `solver`. It's plainly obvious to me that that's true: the lifetime of `solver` ends at the end of the function, and the lifetime of `guess` doesn't. This seems like something the compiler should be able to infer, and compile without error.

Why isn't that the case? Does this code actually have some way for `solver` to outlive `guess`? Or is it just that the compiler doesn't try to do this kind of inference at all?

I know how to fix it --- change the function to `fn foo<'a>(mut solver: Solver<'a>, guess: &'a str)` --- but I'm asking why I should have to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `solver` itself can't outlive `guess`, the lifetime it refers to very well could. For example, imagine invoking `foo()` with a `Solver<'static>`. That kind of solver would expect guess to be `&'static str` and might store the data referred to by `guess` in a global variable. (Remember that the compiler doesn't consider what `register_guess()` does while borrow-checking `foo()`, it just considers its signature.)

More generally, `Solver<'a>` might contain references to `'a` data that outlives `solver` itself. Nothing stops `register_guess()` from storing the contents of guess inside such references. If `guess` isn't guaranteed to live at least as long as `'a`, then `foo()` is simply unsound. For example, take this alternative definition of `Solver`:

```
struct Solver<'a> {
    guesses: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>,
}
```

With unchanged signature of `register_guess()`, `foo()` would allow unsound code like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut guesses = vec![];
    let solver = Solver { guesses: &mut guesses };
    {
        let guess = "foo".to_string();
        // stores temporary "foo" to guesses, which outlives it
        foo(solver, guess.as_str());
    }
    println!("{}", guesses[0]); // UB: use after free
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error comes from rust's rules of [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). One of this rules states that:

> Each elided lifetime in the parameters becomes a distinct lifetime parameter

Rust conservatively assumes that each not specified lifetime is different. If you want some lifetimes to be equal you must specify it explicitly. Your problem is equivalent to simple function that takes two string slices and returns the longer one. You must write the signature of such function as `fn longer<'a>(&'a str, &'a str) -> &'a str`, or the compiler will give you the same error.